# Asian animated film about a boy that grows to be strong and saves village from fire

Tags: story-identification

There was an Asain animated/drawn film that I remember from my childhood where a boy grows up in a village and takes care of his family. There is a specific scene in my head where he is all grown up and is larger than a normal person (though this may be a wrong detail) and saves his village from a fire. In that scene, he is riding his horse that is either made of metal or is covered in metal and the horse is breathing out fire (also may be a wrong detail).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this film? And when you say Asian, do you mean this was Japanese anime, or was it made in another country?

Comment: With the possible exception of a fire breathing horse, which you say may be wrong anyway, this doesn't seem to be science fiction or fantasy.